# How to associate user to orders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Only the admin can create orders. The orders are assigned to a user by user_id. On a users profile page, is the only place where a user can see only their records. I have a feeling the problem is with my controller.

```
    class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = User.find_by(params[:id]).orders.build
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = current_user.orders.build(order_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url, notice: 'Order was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:service, :charge, :user_id)
    end
end
```

This is my users's controller

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @users = User.all
    end

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
          customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => 'example@stripe.com',
    :card  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

          rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to charges_path


    end

    def admin_dashboard
        @users = User.all
    end


    def show

    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete(:password)
      params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
        end

        token = params[:stripeToken]
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
            card: token,
            email: current_user.email
             )

        current_user.stripeid = customer.id
        current_user.save
        redirect_to dashboard_path
    end

    def payment
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit( :stripe_card_token, :avatar, :first_name, :last_name, :country_code, :phone_number,:home_adress,:work_address, :email, :password, :current_password)
    end


end
```

Model User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :orders


end
```

Order Model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Profile Page

```
<div class = 'container'>
    <table class="table table-hover" style = 'width: 70%'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> ID </th>
                    <th> Date </th>
                    <th>Service</th>
                    <th>Charge</th>
                    <th>Feedback</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% Order.all.each do |orders| %>
     <tr>
          <td><%= orders.user.id %></td>
          <td><%= orders.created_at %></td>
          <td><%= orders.service %></td>
          <td><%= orders.charge %></td>
    </tr>
      <%end%>
```

If I'm missing anything please let me know. I'm not sure how I would associate the admin class to all of this.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do. You want to list the orders that belong to the current user? How do you define a user as admin and what do you want it do do?

Comment: I want an admin to be able to create an order for a specific user. When the user goes to his/her dashboard, they can view only their orders.

Comment: So you need to add some logic to the Orders controller and check when a user is Admin and create an order to another user and when the user is listing the orders, it should list only his order, is that it?

Comment: yes thats it. I don't know what I would need to write for that to happen. I've tried a lot of different things but nothing really working. I'm still learning :)

Comment: Enter this chat room and I'll help you there: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44914/ruby-sometimes-on-rails

Comment: ok I just tried to enter, unfortunately I don't have 20 reputation yet :(

Comment: Sorry man, this answer will be too long, is there another way we can chat?

Comment: https://gitter.im/  ?

Comment: https://gitter.im/gerep/VVD-help